# Шаг назад при отладке

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Есть ли в VS2015 шаг назад при отладке? Читаю в интернете что есть, но не пойму где найти его.

Comment: Но как? Ему же придется хранить немаленькие объемы данных... Может вы имеете в виду stack trace?

Comment: Шаг назад нельзя, но можно в середине процедуры для с# сказать "назначить выполнение с этого места" и тогда можно код выполнить повторно указав на код "выше". Сборщик мусора потом "лишнее" уберёт

Comment: Теоретически, для кода на с++ можно сделать шаг назад, если знать ассемблер. Нужно уменьшить в дебагере ассемблера EIP указатель так что б он указывал на нужную команду, но при этом так что б "выжил" стек. Я так делал, несколько раз если попробовать - получится.

Comment: @nick_n_a это очень ограниченный шаг назад, если предыдущая инструкция меняла регистры изменение EIP не вернет их в прежнее состояние.